# How to check sharepoint 2013 Online Logs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Hi I am trying to connect to Sharepoint 2013 online I used basic authentication but the response failed.I want to check the sharpoint 2013 online logs.Kindly suggest me an idea or resource how to check sharepoint online logs.

Answer (score 2):

You can't - ULS logs will be in the server file systems and you don't have any access to the SharePoint Online servers.
You can send the correlation ID to the support desk and they will help you with that.

As a work around, you can make use of the [Windows PowerShell for SharePoint Online cmdlets - Get-SPOAppErrors](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161379.aspx) to get the application monitoring errors.

Hope this helps you.